# In mvc5 how to show icon in navbar after the text?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using:

```
<@Html.ActionLink("logout", "Login", "Account", routevalues:null, htmlattributes: new{@class =glyphicon glyphicon-log-out,  Id="loginLink" })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put a `span` after the `action link` and assign `icon class` to `span`.

```
@Html.ActionLink("logout", "Login", "Account", null,  new{Id="loginLink" })  
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks for.  but it has problem that icon showing separate of link.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Url Helper instead:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Login", "Account")">logout <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></i></a>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Christian Gollhardt. It is working fine.

Comment: @MahammadMoine Thanks for the feedback. Feel free to accepty my answer then :)

Answer (score 0):

This is from my application.

```
 <a href=@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")>Add<i class="fa fa-plus-square-o"></i></a>
```

Hope Its Work !!

Comment: @MahammadMoine Always WelCome  :)